# Using chmod for /usr directory

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

I used the following command to change the permissions of the usr directory from root

root> chmod -R 777 /usr

Now when I try to use the sudo command it gives the following error:
sudo: must be setuid root

On googling, I found that this error happens if /usr is chowned and I need to reinstall Ubuntu. But am I getting this error for chmod? Is there anyway to fix this problem without reinstalling?

Comment: You could boot from a live or rescue CD. But you'll have to figure out what the right permissions are for each file.

Answer (score 1):

To setuid /usr/bin/sudo: chmod +s /usr/bin/sudo.

But you changed ALL file/directory attributes in /usr recursivly (-R). You really should try some rescue mode. I don't think you'll have any chance to repair it.